# Как передать значение из двух разных активностей в третью?

Tags: java, android

Допустим, я передаю из активности 1 в активность 3 некоторое значение. Затем я передаю из активности 2 в активность 3 некоторое значение.
Каким образом затем я могу получить отдельного значение из активности 1 и отдельно значение из активности 2 в третьей, если код вида Intent intent = getIntent(); проинициализирует переменную intent объектом, полученным из последней (второй) активности?

Передаю из первой активности значение в третью, затем перехожу ко второй активности.

```
public class TestPageOne extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_page_one);
        ListView spheres = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list10);

        String[] spheresArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spheres);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                R.layout.listviewtext, spheresArray);
        spheres.setAdapter(adapter);

        spheres.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("sphere", position);
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public void oc10(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(TestPageOne.this, TestPageTwo.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(TestPageOne.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Перейдя во вторую активность, передаю из нее другое значение в третью активность, затем перехожу в третью активность.

```
public class TestPageTwo extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_page_two);

        ListView kinds = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list20);

        String[] kindsArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.kinds);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                R.layout.listviewtext, kindsArray);
        kinds.setAdapter(adapter);

        kinds.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("kind", position);
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public void oc20(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(TestPageTwo.this, Result.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(TestPageTwo.this, TestPageOne.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

В третьей активности обрабатываю два полученных значения

```
public class Result extends AppCompatActivity {

    int sphere, kind;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            int sphere = data.getIntExtra("sphere", 0);
            int kind = data.getIntExtra("kind", 0);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Result.this, TestPageTwo.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: а как вы можете одновременно передавать, если интент 1 по сути

Comment: Не очень понял Ваш вопрос. Но попытаюсь конкретизировать свою задачу: я получаю два различных значениях в двух неодинаковых активностях, и оба значения мне нужно передать в третью активность, чтобы в третьей активности я мог эти значения обработать. Каким образом я могу это сделать?

Comment: мне искренне интересно услышать задачу, которую вы решаете таким способом, возможно вы опишите, что вы делаете и хотите сделать. Что-то мне подсказывает это всё можно проще реализовать

Comment: @alexeypm как были вызваны эти активити. Может использовать https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result?hl=RU например. Потом всё в 1 интент собрать.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @alexeypm один из способов использовать ViewModel и LiveData в которой из первой и второй активити сохранять значения а третья будет подписана на них